# Nested include with offset and limit Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is anyone successful using nested include along with Limit and Offset in Sequelize. I'm trying to implement server side paging using the Sequelize, can anyone show me any reference. I'm using Sql Server database. I see that the query is being converted as sub query along with joins when I try to do this. Has anyone got

```
{where: query.activity,
        attributes: [...activityAttributes, 'LastModifiedUserID', 'LastModifiedDateUTC', 'SPIStatus'],
        include: [
            {
                model: Issue,
                where: query.issue,
                attributes: issueAttributes,
                include: [{
                    model: Product,
                    where: query.product,
                    attributes: productAttributes
                },
                    {
                        model: IssueExtendedAttribute,
                        where: {$and: query.issueExtendedAttributes},
                        required: !!query.issueExtendedAttributes
                    }]
            }],
           offset: 10,
           limit: 10}
```

Comment: Did you fixed it? I am having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729254/sequelize-limit-and-offset-incorrect-placement-in-query?noredirect=1#comment74502903_43729254

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

> subQuery: false;

ex:

```
{
    subQuery: false,
    where: queryObj,
    include: [{
      model: db.A,
      where: AQueryObj,
      include:[{
        model: db.B,
        where: BQueryObj
      },{
        model: db.C,
        where: CQueryObj
      }]
    }],
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit
}
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/kyoyadmoon/picklete/blob/d7c9ee962448a0be9ba2b0f8023c2533add47cd3/api/services/ProductService.js#L433) to get more information