# Sequelize limit and offset incorrect placement in query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize in nodeJs and I have this code:

```
Time_Sheet_Details.findAll({
include: [
    {
        model: timesheetNotesSubcon,
        required: false,
        attributes:["note","file_name", "id", "working_hrs", "timestamp", "has_screenshot", "notes_category"]
    },
    {
        model: Timesheet,
        attributes:["id","leads_id","userid"],
        include:[
            {
                model: Lead_Info, attributes:["id","fname","lname","email","hiring_coordinator_id","status"],
                where: { hiring_coordinator_id : 326},
                include:[{
                    model: adminInfoSchema,
                    required: false,
                    attributes:["admin_id","admin_fname", "admin_lname", "admin_email", "signature_contact_nos", "signature_company"],      
                }]
                
            },
            {model:Personal_Info,attributes:["userid","fname","lname","email"]}
        ],
    }],
where: { 
    reference_date: filters.reference_date
},
order:[
    ["id","DESC"]
],
offset:((1-1)*30),
limit : 30,

}).then(function(foundObject){
    willFulfillDeferred.resolve(foundObject);
});
```

And the result query is:

```
 SELECT `timesheet_details`.*, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`note` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.note`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`file_name` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.file_name`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`id` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.id`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`working_hrs` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.working_hrs`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`timestamp` AS 
`timesheet_notes_subcons.timestamp`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`has_screenshot` AS 
`timesheet_notes_subcons.has_screenshot`, 
`timesheet_notes_subcons`.`notes_category` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.notes_category`, `timesheet.lead`.`id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.id`, `timesheet.lead`.`fname` AS `timesheet.lead.fname`,
 `timesheet.lead`.`lname` AS `timesheet.lead.lname`,
`timesheet.lead`.`email` AS `timesheet.lead.email`,
 `timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.hiring_coordinator_id`, `timesheet.lead`.`status` AS
 `timesheet.lead.status`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_id`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_fname` AS 
`timesheet.lead.admin.admin_fname`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_lname` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_lname`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_email` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_email`, 
`timesheet.lead.admin`.`signature_contact_nos` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.signature_contact_nos`,
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`signature_company` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.signature_company`, `timesheet.personal`.`userid` AS
 `timesheet.personal.userid`, `timesheet.personal`.`fname` AS
 `timesheet.personal.fname`, `timesheet.personal`.`lname` AS
 `timesheet.personal.lname`, `timesheet.personal`.`email` AS
 `timesheet.personal.email` FROM (SELECT `timesheet_details`.`id`,
 `timesheet_details`.`timesheet_id`, `timesheet_details`.`day`,
 `timesheet_details`.`total_hrs`, `timesheet_details`.`adj_hrs`,
 `timesheet_details`.`regular_rostered`, `timesheet_details`.`hrs_charged_to_client`,
 `timesheet_details`.`diff_charged_to_client`,
 `timesheet_details`.`hrs_to_be_subcon`, 
`timesheet_details`.`diff_paid_vs_adj_hrs`, `timesheet_details`.`status`,
 `timesheet_details`.`reference_date`, `timesheet`.`id` AS `timesheet.id`,
 `timesheet`.`leads_id` AS `timesheet.leads_id`, `timesheet`.`userid` AS
 `timesheet.userid` FROM `timesheet_details` AS `timesheet_details` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `timesheet` AS `timesheet` 
ON `timesheet_details`.`timesheet_id` = `timesheet`.`id` 
WHERE (`timesheet_details`.`reference_date` >= '2016-04-23 16:00:00' 
AND `timesheet_details`.`reference_date` < '2017-05-02 15:59:59') 
ORDER BY `timesheet_details`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0, 30) AS
 `timesheet_details` LEFT OUTER JOIN `timesheet_notes_subcon` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons` ON `timesheet_details`.`id` =
 `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`timesheet_details_id` 
INNER JOIN `leads` AS `timesheet.lead` ON `timesheet.leads_id` =
 `timesheet.lead`.`id` AND `timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` = 326
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `admin` AS `timesheet.lead.admin` ON
 `timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` =
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `personal` AS `timesheet.personal` ON `timesheet.userid`
 = `timesheet.personal`.`userid` ORDER BY `timesheet_details`.`id` DESC;
```

As you can see, the `LIMIT 0, 30` is not in the end of the query. This an issue for me because that query will return nothing, and the limit and offset should be at the end of query like this:

```
 SELECT `timesheet_details`.*, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`note` AS
`timesheet_notes_subcons.note`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`file_name` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.file_name`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`id` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.id`, `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`working_hrs` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.working_hrs`,
 `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`timestamp` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.timestamp`,
 `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`has_screenshot` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.has_screenshot`,
 `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`notes_category` AS
 `timesheet_notes_subcons.notes_category`, `timesheet.lead`.`id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.id`, `timesheet.lead`.`fname` AS `timesheet.lead.fname`,
 `timesheet.lead`.`lname` AS `timesheet.lead.lname`,
 `timesheet.lead`.`email` AS `timesheet.lead.email`,
 `timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.hiring_coordinator_id`, `timesheet.lead`.`status` AS
 `timesheet.lead.status`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_id` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_id`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_fname` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_fname`, `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_lname`
 AS `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_lname`,
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_email` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.admin_email`,
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`signature_contact_nos` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.signature_contact_nos`,
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`signature_company` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin.signature_company`, `timesheet.personal`.`userid`
 AS `timesheet.personal.userid`, `timesheet.personal`.`fname` AS
 `timesheet.personal.fname`, `timesheet.personal`.`lname` AS
 `timesheet.personal.lname`, `timesheet.personal`.`email` AS
 `timesheet.personal.email` FROM (SELECT `timesheet_details`.`id`,
 `timesheet_details`.`timesheet_id`, `timesheet_details`.`day`,
 `timesheet_details`.`total_hrs`, `timesheet_details`.`adj_hrs`,
 `timesheet_details`.`regular_rostered`,
 `timesheet_details`.`hrs_charged_to_client`,
 `timesheet_details`.`diff_charged_to_client`,
 `timesheet_details`.`hrs_to_be_subcon`,
 `timesheet_details`.`diff_paid_vs_adj_hrs`,
 `timesheet_details`.`status`, `timesheet_details`.`reference_date`,
 `timesheet`.`id` AS `timesheet.id`, `timesheet`.`leads_id` AS
 `timesheet.leads_id`, `timesheet`.`userid` AS `timesheet.userid` 
FROM `timesheet_details` AS `timesheet_details` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `timesheet` AS `timesheet` ON
 `timesheet_details`.`timesheet_id` = `timesheet`.`id` 
WHERE (`timesheet_details`.`reference_date` >= '2016-04-23 16:00:00' 
AND `timesheet_details`.`reference_date` < '2017-05-02 15:59:59') 
ORDER BY `timesheet_details`.`id` DESC) AS `timesheet_details` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `timesheet_notes_subcon` AS `timesheet_notes_subcons` ON
 `timesheet_details`.`id` =
 `timesheet_notes_subcons`.`timesheet_details_id` INNER JOIN `leads` AS
 `timesheet.lead` ON `timesheet.leads_id` = `timesheet.lead`.`id` AND 
`timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` = 326 LEFT OUTER JOIN `admin` AS
 `timesheet.lead.admin` ON `timesheet.lead`.`hiring_coordinator_id` =
 `timesheet.lead.admin`.`admin_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `personal` AS
 `timesheet.personal` ON `timesheet.userid` =
 `timesheet.personal`.`userid` ORDER BY `timesheet_details`.`id` DESC
 LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in my code? Did I misplaced the order and limit?

Comment: 1. Can you try removing the `include` attribute? 2. What did you mean when you said `that query will return nothing`? If you're not limiting the results the query _should_ return something...

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Hi. Thanks for the response. Can't remove the include. I need all the attributes inside it. What I mean by it returns nothing is because of the limit before the query ends. I need the limit to be at the end of the query, not before.

Comment: Ah lol I see, I did not see the entire result query.

Comment: You could post your issue here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues. You're more likely to get a fast response

Comment: @Yassi its work for me

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari It's ok :D yup, will post on their github as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 90):

Found an answer to my question, I just need to add the `subQuery = false` so that the limit and offset will not be evaluated to sub query. And the offset and limit is also in the end of the query.

```
offset:((page-1)*limit),
limit : limit,
subQuery:false
```

Answer (score 12):

Need to place an order and where clause before includes.Do something like this

```
 user.findAll({
             offset: 5, limit: 5,
            order: [
// Will escape full_name and validate DESC against a list of valid direction parameters
['full_name', 'DESC']]
        }).then(function (result) {
})
```

the resulting query will be

[image]

if you want to put ordering in include then you need to place the order in include part

```
include: [{
                model: taskhelpers, required: true,
                order: {
                    order: '`updatedAt` ASC'
                }
           }]
```

for more detail check [Pagination / Limiting and ordering](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering)

**updated**
nested include and limit and order

```
var option = {
                offset: 5, limit: 5,
            order: [
// Will escape full_name and validate DESC against a list of valid direction parameters
['id', 'DESC']],
                attributes: [
                    'id', 'title',
                    [sequelize.Sequelize.fn('date_format', sequelize.Sequelize.col('date'), '%d-%b-%Y'), 'date']
                ],

                include: [

                    {
                        model: taskhelpers, required: true,

                        where: {
                            userId: req.params.userid,

                            $or: [
                                {
                                    status: {
                                        $eq: "1"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    status: {
                                        $eq: "3"
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                        }

                    }]
            };
```

now pass this option to your model parameter

```
tasks.findAll(options)
    .then(function (result) {
        res.send({message:result,error:null});
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.send({message:null,error:err});
        })
```

this will be the generated query

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example but I also tried putting the limit and offset in the beginning of the code, before that include but still no luck. On your example, I think it will work fine because it's not nested and does not have multiple inner joins?

Comment: Do you require your model before include them?

Answer (score 6):

got the same case, another way of doing it is to pass an array to limit.

```
{
include: [
    {
        model: timesheetNotesSubcon,
        required: false,
        attributes:["note","file_name", "id", "working_hrs", "timestamp", "has_screenshot", "notes_category"]
    },
    {
        model: Timesheet,
        attributes:["id","leads_id","userid"],
        include:[
            {
                model: Lead_Info, attributes:["id","fname","lname","email","hiring_coordinator_id","status"],
                where: { hiring_coordinator_id : 326},
                include:[{
                    model: adminInfoSchema,
                    required: false,
                    attributes:["admin_id","admin_fname", "admin_lname", "admin_email", "signature_contact_nos", "signature_company"],      
                }]

            },
            {model:Personal_Info,attributes:["userid","fname","lname","email"]}
        ],
    }],
where: { 
    reference_date: filters.reference_date
},
order:[
    ["id","DESC"]
],
limit : [((page-1)*limit), limit],

}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### LIMIT,OFFSET,PROJECTION of FIELDS and FULLTEXT SEARCH using sequilize in Node.js

```
        let msg = await Feedback.findAll({
            where: Sequelize.literal('MATCH (message) AGAINST (:feedback)'), // fulltext search query
            replacements: {
            feedback: req.body.text  
            },
            attributes: ['uID', 'message'], // projection of columns
            offset:1, // set the offset according your use case
            limit: 1  // limit the output
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have examined the pagination problem with associated where clause problems in this article.
https://malicaliskan.medium.com/e50dbc9de01d
You can find why the problem occurs, in what conditions and what can be an easy solution to the issue in the article.

Answer (score -3):

try to add $limit parameter on your request and sequelize will use it automatically
ex: "http://localhost:3031/my-service?$limit=23"

Comment: you got to be kidding. the sequelize is just an ORM. it's not going to read the URLs and do the magic. it just acts as a bridge between the application code and database and converts db rows into objects vice versa.